# How to pass an integer constant as generic parameter

Tags: delphi, generics

I need to pass an integer constant as a generic parameter. For example, here is a code for working with a non-standard floating-point numbers (float16) (the code is taken from the githab and slightly modified):

```
const 
  ES = 5;  // exponent size (bits)
  MS = 10; // mantissa size (bits)
           // plus sign (1 bit)
  ESMS = ES + MS;

function FloatXXToSingle(const _in: cardinal): Single;
var
  t1, t2, t3: cardinal;
begin
  t1 := _in and (Cardinal(1 shl ESMS) - 1);               // Non-sign bits
  t2 := _in and (1 shl ESMS);                   // Sign bit
  t3 := _in and ((1 shl ES - 1) shl MS);        // Exponent

  t1 := t1 shl (23 - MS);                       // Align mantissa on MSB
  t2 := t2 shl (31 - ESMS);                     // Shift sign bit into position

  t1 := t1 + cardinal((127-(1 shl (ES-1)-1)) shl 23);   // Adjust bias

  if t3 = 0 then                                // Denormals-as-zero
    t1 := 0;

  t1 := t1 or t2;                               // Re-insert sign bit

  pCardinal(@Result)^ := t1;
end;
```

I want to create a generic on its basis, so that I can set the number of bits for the exponent and mantissa myself. 
Now I'm doing something like this:

```
type
  TFloat<TES, TMS> = class
    const ES = sizeof(TES);
    const MS = sizeof(TMS);
    const ESMS = ES + MS;
    class function ToSingle(const _in: cardinal): Single;
  end;

class function TFloat<TES, TMS>.ToSingle(const _in: cardinal): Single;
var
  t1, t2, t3: cardinal;
begin
  t1 := _in and (Cardinal(1 shl ESMS) - 1);               // Non-sign bits
  t2 := _in and (1 shl ESMS);                   // Sign bit
  t3 := _in and ((1 shl ES - 1) shl MS);        // Exponent

  t1 := t1 shl (23 - MS);                       // Align mantissa on MSB
  t2 := t2 shl (31 - ESMS);                     // Shift sign bit into position

  t1 := t1 + cardinal((127-(1 shl (ES-1)-1)) shl 23);   // Adjust bias

  if t3 = 0 then                                // Denormals-as-zero
    t1 := 0;

  t1 := t1 or t2;                               // Re-insert sign bit

  pCardinal(@Result)^ := t1;
end;
```

But to use this, I have to write something like this:

```
type
  TMyFloat = TFloat<packed record a:Integer; b:Byte; end, packed record a: Extended; end>;

begin
  writeln(TMyFloat.ToSingle($1234));
end.
```

But this method is not at all elegant. Perhaps there is a way to directly pass two numbers to the generic: the size of the exponent and the mantissa?

Comment: You can't do it any better. Well, you could use an array of byte rather than these nasty packed array types because that would be just slightly less opaque. You could do it nicely with C++ templates, but sadly generics aren't as capable. You'd be far better giving up on generics and passing the two sizes as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I, it turns out, misunderstood the phrase from the embarcadero help for generics: "...you can use any type as a type argument except for the following: a static array, a short string, or a record type that (recursively) contains a field of one or more of these two types.". More clear code is: `code`TMyFloat = TFloat<array[1..5] of byte, array[1..10] of byte>;`code` or `code`TMyFloat = TFloat<string[5-1], string[10-1]>;`code`. As for passing parameters to a function as arguments, this will be slower and less safe for code writing.

Comment: Interesting what you say about performance. It's 2.5-3 times faster using versions with compile time constants.

Comment: For my test this is not confirmed. Compile time constants version is apporx. 1.5 times slower than generic one (as I expected, but I expected a bigger difference). My computer is Pentium Dual Core E5200 2.5 GHz, Delphi XE5, Optimization is on.

Comment: Generic version is compile time constants. That's the whole point of the generic version.  I'm comparing that against a version passing the two sizes as arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I have a slightly more complicated test: I run all possible numbers to float16, and then back to Single and perform some additional checks, so, probably, my difference turned out to be less than yours.

Comment: I must admit that I was surprised by the difference. It's not pretty but sometimes performance trumps beauty.

Comment: let's hope that language developers will improve generics in future versions of Delphi.

Comment: We can hope but I think that hope is in vain.

Comment: Passing integral **values** as parameters to a **type** is not possible. You can only pass types. You probably want something like `TFloat16 = TFloat<5, 10>` or `TFloat32 = TFloat<8, 23>`. That is not possible.

Comment: @Rudy We already covered all of this

Comment: @David: If you did, I don't see it.

Comment: @rudy Very first comment.

Comment: @David: you could use an array of byte rather than these nasty packed array types because that would be just slightly less opaque" That would be a type, not an integer value. It is not said anywhere that you simply can't pass anything but types, and not integer values, like in C++.

Comment: @Ridy Very first sentence of that comment